# Deck rail position

Tags: decking

Building a deck for a treehouse project. Installed deck posts inside rim joists with blocking. Question: is it better to install the 2x4 top/bottom rails on the inside or the outside of the deck posts? I could see how installing inside is stronger but then you lose a bit of deck space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rails have rotted to the point that **proper hardware** no longer holds them in place, being inside the posts won't offer much more security.

If you're going to install them inappropriately (*i.e.*, nailing) the position would matter more.

For a railing that will be leaned against, something like carriage bolts, fender washers, lockwashers, and nuts would be *a* version of "proper hardware." Purpose-made brackets would also be *a* version.